# Perl extracting data from a hash

Tags: perl, hash

I am trying to extract data from a hash value.

```
   my $triggers = $zabbix->raw('trigger','get', $options);
   print Dumper($triggers);

    foreach my $trigger (@{$triggers} )
    {

    push @triggerid,$trigger->{'triggerid'};

    my @t=$trigger->{'hosts'};
    my $lt = localtime($trigger->{'lastchange'});
    print "$trigger->{'description'} $lt \n";

    }
```

Output of Dumper is

```
[
   {
        'hosts' => [
                     {
                       'hostid' => '19914',
                       'host' => 'pc10bcf18.syd.sf.priv'
                     }
                   ],
        'priority' => '2',
        'status' => '0',
        'templateid' => '10652913',
        'comments' => '',
        'state' => '0',
        'triggerid' => '10653191',
        'expression' => '{15070357}#1',
        'error' => '',
        'url' => '',
        'flags' => '0',
        'value' => '1',
        'name' => 'pc10_BizX_A_CF',
        'description' => 'pc10bcf18.syd.sf.priv: Core Path not \'/dumps/java/core\' (Path=/export/home/jboss/j...)',
        'value_flags' => '0',
        'lastchange' => '1429181103',
        'type' => '0'
      },
]
```

From my above code, i was able to print 'description'. How do i access and print the value of 'host' value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain the `for` / `push` pattern that you have already coded, you can write this

```
my $triggers = $zabbix->raw('trigger', 'get', $options);

my @triggerid;

for my $trigger ( @$triggers ) {

  push @triggerid, $trigger->{triggerid};

  my @hosts;
  my $hosts = $trigger->{hosts};
  for my $host ( @$hosts ) {
    push @hosts, $host->{host};
  }

  my $lt = localtime($trigger->{lastchange});
  print "$trigger->{description} $lt\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there can be more than one host, so

```
my @hosts =
   map { $_->{host} }
      @{ $trigger->{hosts} };
```

To get the first one (assuming there will always be at least one),

```
my $first_host = $trigger->{hosts}[0]{host};
```

Answer (score -1):

`$triggers->{'hosts'}->[0]->{'host'}`